# Grant user privileges docker init script Postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker

i have a script as follows

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "...:::AUTO-KONTO - INITIALIZING POSTGRESQL WITH DEFAULT DATA:::...."

# creates new db and new user who is owner of this db
# arg1 db name
# arg2 user name
# arg3 user pass
create_db_user_pass() {
    psql --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname "$POSTGRES_DB" -c "CREATE USER $2 WITH PASSWORD '$3'" && \
    psql --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname "$POSTGRES_DB" -c "CREATE DATABASE $1 OWNER=$2"
 }

# executes sql on given DB
# arg1 db name
# arg2 sql to execute
exec_sql() {
    psql --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname "$1" -c "$2"
}
create_db_user_pass keycloak       keycloak          password
create_db_user_pass autkontodb     admin             admin
```

So far i have this script and it works but i want to grant previledges to admin and keycloak , currently both users cant create table or delete a table. Please how can i do it ?

Comment: Your script looks fine, how do you know it's not working? are you getting an error?

Comment: yes this script is fine but i am trying to add previledges but not show how to write it, i want to grant previledges to user admin

Comment: If I understood you correctly you will need to run `ALTER ROLE ... WITH ...`. Please read this https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterrole.html.

Comment: yes i have seen this, but i havent been able to apply it on a script.sh, i am new to shell writing